# Uploading projects from local computer to server by using Gitlab

Tags: upload, gitlab

I am completely new to Gitlab because previously I upload project to server using Filezilla. But now I have finished my Laravel projects in my local computer, and I would like to upload it to my could hosting. Currently my project is stored in `c:\\xampp\htdocs\myproject`.

Please tell me command line step-by-step to achieve this? I am using Putty on window. I can't understand it by reading existing tutorial.

Comment: Does your server host a GitLab server? Or are you talking about a repo hosted by gitlab.com?

Comment: I use DigitalOcean.com's server and yes I registered on gitlab.com to store/upload my project to the server.

Answer (score 0):

> I use DigitalOcean.com's server and yes I registered on gitlab.com to store/upload my project.

As a first approach, you can push directly to DigitalOcean, [as describe in this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps):

- clone your GitLab repo as a bare repo on your DigitalOcean instance (VPS: Virtual Private Server or Droplet)

  ```
   cd
   git clone --bare https://gitlab.com/<yourUsername>/<yourRepo.git>
  ```
- add a post-receive hook similar to this [auto-deploy article](http://luxiyalu.com/git-auto-deploy/)

That is:

```
cat > /home/rails/rails_project.git/hooks/post-receive

(Copy-paste the following lines)

#!/bin/sh

echo "-----------------------------------"
echo "Post receive hook: Updating website"

export GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/yourProject
export GIT_DIR=/home/yourUser/yourRepo.git

cd $GIT_WORK_TREE
git pull
git checkout master -f

(type Ctrl+D to exit)
```

Depending on your deployment path, you might have to execute the git commands as root, but it is best if you can keep your deployment as your username and not root.

---

But if you don't want to push to DigitalOcean, only to GitLab, you can use instead [**Git-Auto-Deploy**](https://github.com/olipo186/Git-Auto-Deploy).

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1056476/9344294/d3bc32a4-4607-11e5-9a44-5cd9b22e61d9.png]

Then you can push to GitLab, and that will trigger a deployment to your VPS.

> When commits are pushed to your Git repository, the Git server will notify Git-Auto-Deploy by sending a HTTP POST request with a JSON body to a pre configured URL (your-host:8001).
>   The JSON body contains detailed information about the repository and what event that triggered the request.
>   Git-Auto-Deploy parses and validates the request, and if all goes well it issues a `git pull`.
>
> Additionally, Git-Auto-Deploy can be configured to execute a shell command upon each successful `git pull`, which can be used to trigger custom build actions or test scripts.

Comment: Thank you but I still am lost.

Comment: @Devith First, do you want to deploy your project when you push to GitLab or when you push directly to DigitalOcean?

Comment: I want to copy my project from local computer to gitlab. Then I want to upload it to the server. Is that practical way? If yes/no, please advise with Step 1: ... Step 2:.. until the project is live.